# Langchain OpenAI invoke - unexpected keyword argument "functions"

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

```py
    from langchain.schema import HumanMessage, SystemMessage, AIMessage
    from langchain_openai import OpenAI
    from langchain.chains.openai_functions.tagging import create_tagging_chain
    from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
    from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
    from langchain.utils.openai_functions import convert_pydantic_to_openai_function
    from langchain.output_parsers.openai_functions import JsonOutputFunctionsParser
    
    api_key = 'api-key'
    import os
    os.environ['OPENAI_API_TOKEN'] = api_key
    
    
    llm = OpenAI(api_key=api_key, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k", temperature=0)
    
    schema = {
        "properties":{
            "sentiment": {"type": "string", "enum": ["Positive", "Neutral", "Negative", "Unidentified"]},
            "rootcause":{"type": "string", "description": "This is the root cause of the review"},
        },
        "required": ["sentiment", "rootcause"],
    }
    
    
    
    class GetEnrichment(BaseModel):
        """Get the sentiment of the review"""
        sentiment: str = Field(description="What is the sentiment of this review? Possible options are [Positive,Neutral,Negative,Unidentified] ")
        rootcause: str = Field(description="What is the root cause of the review?")
    
    getenrichment_function = [convert_pydantic_to_openai_function(GetEnrichment)]
    
    enrich_model = llm.bind(
        functions=getenrichment_function,
        function_call={"name":"Enriching"}
    )
    
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
        "system", "Identify the sentiment and root causes from the given review."
    ])
    review1= "STAY AWAY FROM THEM. DO NOT BUY ANYTHING FROM THEM."
    
    whole_chain = prompt | enrich_model | JsonOutputFunctionsParser()
    
    print(whole_chain.invoke({"input": review1}))
```

error is this:

```
> File "c:\Users\LLMsutil\Enrichment_langchain2.py", line 45, in <module>   
    print(whole_chain.invoke({"input": review1}))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\LLMsutil\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 2053, in invoke
    input = step.invoke(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\runnables\base.py", line 3887, in invoke
    return self.bound.invoke(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\LLMsutil\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 230, in invoke
    self.generate_prompt(
  File "c:\Users\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 525, in generate_prompt
    return self.generate(prompt_strings, stop=stop, callbacks=callbacks, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\LLMsutil\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 698, in generate
    output = self._generate_helper(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 562, in _generate_helper
    raise e
  File "c:\Users\LLMsutil\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\llms.py", line 549, in _generate_helper
    self._generate(
  File "c:\Users\LLMsutil\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_openai\llms\base.py", line 340, in _generate
    response = self.client.create(prompt=_prompts, **params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\.venv\Lib\site-packages\openai\_utils\_utils.py", 
line 271, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Completions.create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'functions'
```

Package versions:

```
langchain==0.1.4
langchain-community==0.0.16
langchain-core==0.1.16
langchain-openai==0.0.5
langsmith==0.0.84
numpy==1.26.3
openai==1.10.0
```

It's probably the version of langchain I'm using, but not sure why I get this error for "functions". What am I missing?
I want to also use "langchain.chains.openai_functions.tagging.create_tagging_chain" but gives the same error when I tried. However, "create_extraction_chain" did work just fine, when using model.invoke().