# Langchain python tagging

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

I am trying to reproduce an example from [Langchain](https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/introduction) documentation, I copied the example about tagging (after configuring environment variables)

But I get the following error :

```
TypeError: Completions.create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'functions'
```

When I run the following example :

```
from langchain.chains import Create_tagging_chain,create_tagging_chain_pydantic
from langchain import LLMChain, PromptTemplate
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAI
import os

AZURE_ENDPOINT=os.getenv("AZURE_ENDPOINT")
GPT_DEPLOYMENT_NAME=os.getenv("GPT_DEPLOYMENT_NAME")
OPENAI_API_KEY=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

# Schema
schema = {
    "properties": {
        "sentiment": {"type": "string"},
        "aggressiveness": {"type": "integer"},
        "language": {"type": "string"},
    }
}

llm = AzureOpenAI(
azure_endpoint=AZURE_ENDPOINT,
openai_api_version="2023-07-01-preview",
azure_deployment=GPT_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY,
openai_api_type="azure",temperature=0.9
)

chain = create_tagging_chain(schema, llm)

inp = "Estoy increiblemente contento de haberte conocido! Creo que seremos muy buenos amigos!"
chain.run(inp)
```

Comment: There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77905570/12559207), although it is also without an answer.